# SQL Server 2016 - Array into separate columns

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I'm tasked with importing data into SQL thats pretty much JSON but not quite . I've used OPENROWSET/OPENJSON to import into a staging table and the data looks like this

[image]

What I need to achieve is migrate that to a single table with the following structure

[image]

I'm having no success , I even trying updating the data in the staging table to look like this and import but no joy.

[image]

My current attempt:

```
SELECT A.[DATE], A.[VALUE] 
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) AS I 
CROSS APPLY ( 
   SELECT * 
   FROM OPENJSON (@JSON) WITH ( 
      [DATE] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.DATE', 
      [VALUE] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.VALUE' 
   ) 
) A OUTPUT
```

Any recommendations ?

Comment: Look at `OPENJSON`.

Comment: What is your current attempt? The text in the `array` column is a valid JSON and using `OPENJSON` and the appropriate columns definitions is a working solution.

Comment: I had tried 
SELECT  A.[DATE], A.[VALUE]
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) 
  AS I
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENJSON (@JSON) 
   WITH (
      [DATE] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.DATE',
      [VALUE] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.VALUE'
   )
) A
OUTPUT:  but that purely returned NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this way:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
instance NVARCHAR(50),
json NVARCHAR(1000)
)


 INSERT #tmp
 VALUES
 (   N'server1.com', 
     N'[{"date":10000, "value":"6"},{"date":20000, "value":"8"}]'
  )

SELECT
    t.instance, Date,Value
FROM #tmp t
OUTER  APPLY OPENJSON(t.json)
WITH (   
              Date   varchar(200) '$.date' ,  
              Value     VARCHAR(100)     '$.value'
              
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first set of data, you have a doubly-nested JSON array, so you need to use `OPENJSON` to break open the outer one first:

```sql
SELECT
    instance
    JSON_VALUE(j1.innerArray, '$[0]') AS date,
    JSON_VALUE(j1.innerArray, '$[1]') AS value
FROM table t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.json) WITH (
   innerArray nvarchar(max) '$' AS JSON
) j1
```

For the second version, just change the `JSON_VALUE` parameters:

```sql
    JSON_VALUE(j1.innerArray, '$.date') AS date,
    JSON_VALUE(j1.innerArray, '$.value') AS value
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer:**

The reason for the unexpected result is the fact, that the you have nested JSON arrays, but the `WITH` clause is not correct. You need to use the appropriate `WITH` clause, like the statement below:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('server1.com', '[[1613347200, "7"], [1613347205, "8"], [1613347202, "9"]]'),
   ('server2.com', '[[1613317200, "3"], [1613347215, "2"], [1613347212, "1"]]')
) v (instance, array)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.instance, j.[date], j.[value]
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.array) WITH (
   [date] numeric(10, 0) '$[0]',
   [value] varchar(1) '$[1]'
) j
```

Result:

```
instance    date        value
-----------------------------
server1.com 1613347200  7
server1.com 1613347205  8
server1.com 1613347202  9
server2.com 1613317200  3
server2.com 1613347215  2
server2.com 1613347212  1
```

**Update:**

Your second attempt is almost correct. The reason for the `NULL` values is the fact, that the `path` part of the columns definitions in the `WITH` clause is case sensitive:

```
SELECT d.instance, j.[date], j.[value]
FROM (VALUES
   ('server1.com', '[{"date":1613347200, "value":"7"}, {"date":1613347200, "value":"8"}]')
) d (instance, array)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.array) WITH (
   [date] numeric(10, 0) '$.date',
   [value] varchar(1) '$.value'
) j
```